The script gives me an error saying no monobehaviour scripts in the file... and even after fixing it, it still crashes
I am Korean, so the sentences may be strange.
enter image description here
As in the title above, an error occurs in the script. The file name and the script name are the same, and Visual Studio works well with an error message or a color display.enter image description here
I reinstalled Visual Studio, but it didn't work. The solution was to change it from Debug mode to Release mode. However, when I try to edit the scene and save it, Unity crashes, and when I re-enter, it initializes and the error occurs again.
enter image description here
How can I solve this? If you don't understand, please ask questions. Also, what is Release mode and how can it be solved? I am also curious about why it crashes.
P.s This is the error that appears in the console.
enter image description here
I tried to upload a photo that crashed, but this time I didn't get an error. I don't know why, but it happens sometimes.

it doesnt seem to be crashing.. its just not working.  Did you change anything to do with the domain reload, or recompilation options?

The script you're showing seems incomplete? public bool isOn = true; ? Also, please include your actual code here, and not just an image of your code.

can you also check there are no errors in the console

On the first screenshot it looks like the name of the script has spaces in between words, like "Ambient On Off", I think it should't have space in between.

Actually @PavlosMavris Ive seen that in unity 6, it must AI the thing to what it thinks is cool..  unity 6 also doesnt seem to insist on the exact name of the class matching the filename either

@Bart The reason I wrote the script incompletely is to show that errors are underlined in red, i.e. Visual Studio is working properly.

@BugFinder I added a picture of the console window. And now that I've turned my laptop off and on and switched to release mode and saved, it doesn't crash. That's good for now, but it will happen again someday.
